# Zipping Epub: Mimetype file should contain only the string "application/epub+zip"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, zip, epub, mime-types

I followed the tutorial [Build a digital book with EPUB](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-epubtut/)
to create an ePUB file. 
The `mimetype` file contains only `application/epub+zip`
and should not be compressed. 
However, the zip commands that were recommended
to achieve the non-compression of mimetype,

```
zip -0Xq   ebook.epub mimetype
zip -Xr9Dq ebook.epub *
```

...produce the following error when I run [epubcheck](http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/):

```
ERROR: ebook.epub/mimetype: Mimetype file should contain only the string "application/epub+zip".
```

So I tried two other combinations of zip options, but the error stays the same.

```
zip -X  ebook.epub mimetype 
zip -rg ebook.epub META-INF 
zip -rg ebook.epub OEBPS

zip -X0  ebook.epub mimetype
zip -rX9 ebook.epub * -x mimetype
```

However, Calibre will open any of these Ebooks without any problems.

The content of my `mimetype` file is correct, so that it must be a problem with the `zip` commands. Or could this a bug of epubcheck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the characters `\n` and `\r` from the `mimetype` file
using Linux’s `tr` command as follows:

```
tr -d '\n' < mimetype   > mimetype.1
tr -d '\r' < mimetype.1 > mimetype.2
rm mimetype mimetype.1 
mv mimetype.2 mimetype
```

or simply

```
tr -d '\n\r' < mimetype > mimetype.2
mv mimetype.2 mimetype
```

And then you will have to add the file mimetype to the ePUB file using the following command:

```
zip -0Xq book.epub mimetype
```

Then you need to add remaining files to ePUB files as follows:

```
zip -Xr9Dq book.epub * -x mimetype -x book.epub
```

Then just validate it using the online [EPUB Validator](http://validator.idpf.org/)
and you will get a NO ERROR regarding mimetype.

Comment: It is not necessary to modify the `mimetype` file. You can create it directly without the newline: `echo -n application/epub+zip >mimetype`.

Comment: I tried it with the echo command and your zip commands and epubcheck does not bring this error message anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

open the minetype file in dreamweaver or any text editing software and delete any spaces after the line that says 'application/epub+zip'. Make sure there isn't any returns as well.

That should work

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Mac, running "ePub Zip/Unzip 3.0" (an Applescript that contains the correct zip commands, etc.) and I got this error too.

It turns out that both BBEdit and TextWrangler have a Preferences setting that automatically adds an additional line-break when you save. I unchecked that preference, and no more error.

Check your text editor to see if it has such a preference, and turn it off, if you can. (In BBEdit, it's called "Ensure file ends with line break" under the "Text Files" Preference.)

Best!

Todd